# Old symbol for the first person pronoun

Tags: fonts, symbols

The symbol for the first person pronoun used to have a different and peculiar shape before the onset of computers. Now we simply use "I". How may I access this symbol?

Comment: Got a picture so that we know what you're talking about?

Comment: Are you sure? In which language? Before the onset of *computers*? Why should that have influenced the typesetting of books, for example, which continued to be set with metal type for some time, but which do not use anything different from 'I'. At least, none of the books I've seen use anything else and plenty of them will have been set with metal type. (I don't have really old books, but I have some and certainly read library books old enough for *that*.)

Comment: In English - I should have said that, but I didn't think of any other languages where the letter "I" is the first person personal pronoun. 

This is how I remember it from school in Norway. Possibly I associate with a form of the letter which was recommended writing.

Comment: I'm English and I would not be able to guess what symbol you have in mind, the word is just "I" computers or not.